# How to remove index in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame I want to restructure for using in a loop.
The frame looks like this

```
       ryr    trst      lstkw       level            
year                                 2014        2015
0     1990  Diesel  100-140kW   11.843030   11.843030
1     1990  Diesel   60-100kW  217.817005  217.817005
2     1990  Diesel      <60kW  100.713126  100.713126
3     1990    Elec      <60kW    6.253120    6.253120
4     1990     GAS  100-140kW    0.094744    0.094744
```

And I want to have it looked like this(remove the "level")

```
       ryr    trst      lstkw        2014        2015        
0     1990  Diesel  100-140kW   11.843030   11.843030
1     1990  Diesel   60-100kW  217.817005  217.817005
2     1990  Diesel      <60kW  100.713126  100.713126
3     1990    Elec      <60kW    6.253120    6.253120
4     1990     GAS  100-140kW    0.094744    0.094744
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Renger

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)` ?

Comment: You have to provide your code which have tried by you so far

Comment: Thanks manwithnewfeeds. That did the job. Sorry for not posting the code

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd 

# Creating the Index 
idx = pd.Index(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']) 

# to delete 
idx.delete([ column number])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant to the OP's issue